# Where is Xserver log file located?

Tags: xorg, log

My Ubuntu 10.10 sometimes totally freezes. I suppose that it is somehow related to my graphic card and would like to check Xserver log. Where is this file located ?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Where most of log files located: `/var/log/`

Log filename: `Xorg.0.log` `Xorg.1.log` etc...

Update:

You can check out the log files:

Click on

**System menu** > **Choose Administration** > **System Log**

or

**Applications** > **System Tool** > **Log File Viewer**

Answer (score 36):

`/var/log/` [as mentioned](https://askubuntu.com/a/26526/1614008), or `~/.local/share/xorg/`:

> If a problem occurs, view the log stored in either `/var/log/` or, for
> the rootless X default since v1.16, in `~/.local/share/xorg/`.
>
> - [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xorg#General)

Note that `~` is a home directory of an user who starts xserver. This user could be `gdm3` for example and in such case you will find logs at `/var/lib/gdm3/.local/share/xorg`.