# Where is the XServer log file located in 18.04 and later

Tags: 18.04, xorg, systemd-journald

I know the answer to this question, I've been looking there for years and its here too: [Where is Xserver log file located?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26525)

Only it isn't - it's December 2020 and I'm logged into the desktop, but there are no logs since July (probably when I updated from 16.04 to 18.04)

```
$ ls -la /var/log/Xorg.*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 133637 Jul 23 19:38 /var/log/Xorg.0.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  94763 Jul 23 16:31 /var/log/Xorg.0.log.old
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   6382 Sep  2  2014 /var/log/Xorg.1.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  65653 Jun 18  2014 /var/log/Xorg.1.log.old
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  21314 May 27  2014 /var/log/Xorg.failsafe.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     64 May 27  2014 /var/log/Xorg.failsafe.log.old
```

Any ideas?

Comment: on my 18.04 system it's at /var/log perhaps your graphics driver defaulted to Nouveau when you updated?

Answer (score 2):

This is perhaps not as intuitive as everyone might think.  For my ubuntu mate 18.04 system using lightdm for the display manager I have valid data in `/var/log/lightdm/x-#.log.`

The user xsession log sould be in $HOME.

This answer is definitely not comprehensive.

Answer (score 0):

Ok - it seems like the answer depends on what the definition of "is" is ;)

In earlier versions of ubuntu things may have been simpler, but there are a number of possible variations on how the desktop is presented, relating to systemd sessions and/or X or Wayland.  I have seen some variations on machines I've looked for and provide info here, this is not complete.

1. X(org) running as root for display manager and/or user session: logs in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` (display manager), `/var/log/Xorg.1.log` additional (user) sessions

- for example nVidia proprietary driver

2. X(org) running as user in a user session: `$HOME/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log`

- for example AMD drivers (probably intel too)

3. XWayland running a display manager: no Xorg logs - I'm not sure where to look for wayland errors - I'm guessing `journalctl`?

- for example AMD drivers (probably intel too)

I would assume its possible to have gdm run as user `gdm` on X(org), but I haven't seen such a configuration.

If anyone has any links to real references on desktop architecture of Ubuntu, X, Wayland and user sessions I'd be really interested.